# Single activity rendering two views

Tags: android

I have divided my layout into half, left side is having all the buttons.
Right side of the layout should show the button clicked activity.
I am using android 2.2, this is particularly for  extra large screens as in small screens main activity would have just buttons,clicking on buttons would take to new activity but for extra large screens all of these images and buttons looks very small, so now  divided the layout left for buttons and right for rendering those particular activities.
Any pointers or code examples would be really helpful.

Tried fragments in android 2.2 but fragments only work after android 3. So looking forward to your reply.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Fragments api was backported almost immediately after it was released.  Use the information in the following blog post from the Android Developers blog to use this library in your apps that support API versions less than 3.0

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

**EDIT**

Here's a better link with pictures and more detailed instructions

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-compatibility-working-with-fragments/

Comment: thanks. I already have the application, needed to convert those layouts for extra large screens. Any links for converting would be helpful as the fragments should call activities.

Comment: Poke around the tutsplus site.  The same group that posted the tutorial linked above for importing the library also has a whole series on Android development that consists of converting a master-detail workflow into fragments for large screen and navigating on normal/small screen.  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_fragments/